# Pencil of rank 2 quadrics

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have been told the following fact about pencils of quadrics of rank at most $2$, where the rank of a quadric is the rank of the defining symmetric matrix. That the quadric has rank at most $2$ corresponds to saying that it is the union of two hyperplanes; its defining equation can be split into two linear forms.

Let $l_1, l_2, l_3, l_4$ be linear forms defining the generators $l_1l_2$ and $l_3l_4$ of the pencil. Then either a hyperplane is fixed in the pencil, that is, $l_3$ is for instance a scalar multiple of $l_1$, or $l_3$ and $l_4$ are linear combinations of $l_1$ and $l_2$.

How do I prove this?